# Boot Failed. EFI DVD/CDROM

Tags: parallels-desktop, macos

I am trying to install El Capitan *Public* beta version ([available here](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/redemption#osx)) in Parallels Desktop version 10.2.2.  I followed [this tutorial](http://www.lostentropy.com/2015/06/10/installing-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-inside-parallels-desktop/) to create the bootable dmg and mounted it in a new VM that I created.  When I start the VM it says...

```
Boot Failed. EFI Hard Drive
Boot Failed. EFI DVD/CDROM
```

...and then falls to EFI Shell as shown below.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: The [Parallels Desktop for Mac - Forum](https://forum.parallels.com/forums/parallels-desktop-for-mac.58/) is probably a better place to be asking questions regarding Parallels Desktop for Mac.

Comment: @user3439894 good point.  I created a new thread at https://forum.parallels.com/threads/os-x-el-capitan-boot-failed-efi-dvd-cdrom.329110/  I will answer this question if/when I get a response there.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me too. And looking for options I found this which works better with VMWare Fusion 8 on Mac.

It is a shell script which with just one command create a Bootable DMG file and then you can create a Virtual Machine from that DMG and that's it.

https://github.com/rtrouton/create_os_x_vm_install_dmg

- What I did is to uncompress the file found at `create_os_x_vm_install_dmg-master/support/First_Boot_Package_Install.zip`
- The correct command that works for me was `sudo ./create_vmware_osx_install_dmg.sh "/Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app" /Users/[your_user]/Desktop/`

I hope it could be useful for you like me!
Any question ask me at [@Lexynux](https://twitter.com/Lexynux)

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link:  http://kb.parallels.com/en/5029  Follow the instructions on how to remove a virtual machine.  Once you do this, then you will be returned to the screen where you first started.  I remember what got me into this mess was choosing the setting where I could do the Custom settings.  DO NOT check this setting and everything will be fine.  I was able to get Windows 10 to install.  All is well now.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Rey.  I ended up installing Yosemite and then upgrading to El Capitan.